# Intentando conectar a una api Externa desde wordpress

Tags: asp.net, api, wordpress, rest

Tengo un detalle cuando intento hacer peticiones al servidor remoto tienen que estar en los puertos 80 o ssl(443) para que funcione. pero si lo coloco en otros puertos wordpress no conecta. He probado con otras herramientras para ver si es el servidor remoto el del problema, pero no, todo sigue igual. Wordpress por alguna razon solo lee puertos 80 y 433 y rechaza cualquier otro que se configure.

Comment: Aloha~ buen día :D ¿Cómo podemos reproducir tu escenario?

Comment: Es un localhost? Por favor lee [ask] y haz el [tour]